# How to fetch Multiple Records as a single Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Above result set have three values that in first row `timeone` and `timetwo` have values, rather `timethree`, `timefour`, `timefive` and `timesix` have null values, it follows for other four columns.

How can i fetch all these in a single row ?

Comment: Pivot..........

Comment: ISNUL(timeone,'01:00:03') .... so On and use select DISTINCT

Answer (score 5):

Just perform aggregation:

```
SELECT ID,NAME,Age, 
       MAX(timeone) AS timeone,
       MAX(timetwo) AS timetwo,
       MAX(timethree) AS timethree,
       MAX(timefour) AS timefour,
       MAX(timefive) AS timefive,
       MAX(timesix) AS timesix
FROM [table]
GROUP  BY ID,NAME,Age;
```

Comment: @Shahul You can accept the answer if it helps you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) ID,NAME,AGE, (SELECT TOP(1) TIMEONE from [TABLE] WHERE ID = [ID] AND TIMEONE 
is not null)
FROM [TABLE]
```

the nested select will get the time part you want for the first result, you can five more queries like this in order to get the rest of the times.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join query as below:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.name, t.age, t.timeone, t.timetwo, t1.timethree, t1.timefour, t2.timefive, t2.timesix 
FROM 
    (SELECT Id, name, age, timeone, timetwo FROM [Table] WHERE timeone is not null and timetwo is not null) as t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Id, timethree, timefour FROM [Table] WHERE timethree is not null and timefour is not null) as t1 
ON t.Id = t1.Id INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Id, timefive, timesix FROM [Table] WHERE timefive is not null and timesix is not null) as t2 
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

The query is a little bit larger. But I have tried to resolve it in another way as one of the guys have already given a right answer.